# How do I read the nested json object to table in Angular?

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to read a json data that's nested and display it using a table, but when I try to read the nested parts it displays an [object][object]. I tried a json pipe but it doesn't give the desired results. Can someone suggest the best method to solve this ?

Here's the same code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-obccw3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVTTr.jpg)

Comment: Issue: You need to convert the object to a human-readable string. Potential solution: Create an `address` pipe

Comment: tried a pipe, but it doesn't work on the object

Comment: What are **the desired results**?

Comment: gets me the same entire data again as an object

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution could be parse the address in a method, and instead of nested loop of columns should try something like this.

```
<tr *ngFor="let char of characters">
  <td>{{char.id}}</td>
  <td> {{char.name}} </td>
  <td> {{char.username}} </td>
  <td> {{char.email}}</td>
  <td> {{getAddress(char)}}</td>
</tr>
```

parse the address in `getAddress` method in component.

```
getAddress(char) {
 return `${char.address.street} ${char.address.suite} ${char.address.city}`
}
```

forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ftxqrb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example you can check it out